# When Dragging and Dropping QTreeWidgetItems within a QTreeWidget, how can I catch the Item that was moved so i can retrieve its new parent?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt

I have a simple TreeWidget populated with subclassed TreeWidgetItems. When one of these Items is moved through an Internal Drag and Drop event, how do I catch the Item that was moved?

When the Item is moved, I want to catch the item so i can get its new parent item.

I have tried using an eventFilter to look for a ChildRemoved event, but when I ask the event for the child, it returns a generic QObject, instead of my subclassed item. What am I missing?

```
def eventFilter(self, sender, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ChildRemoved:
        widgetItemThatMoved = event.child()
        self.updateSomething(widgetItemThatMoved)
    return False
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you will need to implement a dragEnterEvent, dragMoveEvent and dropEvent

To access the dropped QTreeWidgetItem(s), you do that right inside the dropEvent

```
class myTreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(myTreeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)


    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        print('dragEnterEvent happened')
        event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        print('dragMoveEvent happened')
        event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        print('dropEvent happened')
        widgetItemThatMoved=event.source().currentItem()
        parentThatReceivedIt=self.itemAt(event.pos())
        self.theFunc(parentThatReceivedIt,widgetItemThatMoved )
        event.acceptProposedAction()

    def functionToCallWhenDropped(self,theFunc):
        #this method allows you to pass a reference to this class so you assign it to a local variable for easy calling.
        self.theFunc=theFunc
```

It will be nice to add an extra method functionToCallWhenDropped so that you can have access to the parent class method, in the parent class, you will do something like this

```
 def someMethod(self):
        self.tw=myTreeWidget(parent)
        self.tw.functionToCallWhenDropped(self.wasDropped)

    def wasDropped(self, newParent, theMovedChild):
        #this method will be called the very moment you drop the item
        print(newParent.text(0)+" => "+theMovedChild.text(0))
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hey @Ajayi Oluwaseun Emmanuel
Correct me if I'm wrong but this only return last item selected. How can I return all selected items after drag? So If I drag 5 items, I have 5 pointers to new items ?